# Mongo DB: ValidationError: User validation failed: username: Path `username` is required

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When I am trying to Save/Create a New Document (User) to Mongo DB using Mongoose, I am getting the following Validation Error in spite of providing all the Values with proper DataType:

ValidationError: User validation failed: username: Path username is required.

I am a Beginner at Node JS and Mongo DB. Hence I am not able to understand what is going wrong.

I have also added the following modules:

Express
Mongo
Mongoose

**Detailed error**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBTx6.png)

**User Schema/ Model**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9xH3.png)

**User Controller**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxGAD.png)

I just don't understand, why I am getting this Validation Error. Can anybody please guide me through this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text

Answer (score 1):

this is because in the post request you are not filling the username field,why is this happening:
it could be one of these:

1. you did not put a name tag for the input in your front end
2. you copied the name wrong`(req.body.[wrongname])`
3. you added the name wrongly to the database. `new userModel({username: [wrong data]})`

I will give you an example of sending username to mongo with node.

1. you should install `bodyParser` and `mongoose (npm I body-parser, npm I mongoose)`
2. consider below code

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String
  }
})

let userModel = new mongoose.Model('users', userSchema);
app.get('/signup', (req, res) => {
  res.render('signup')
})

app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  let newUser = new userModel({
    username: username
  })
  newUser.save(function (err, doc) {
    res.send(doc)
  });
})
```